# local variable 'password1' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

so i have been follow Django Documentation example regarding Custom user Model (AbstractBaseUser). But when i create user from admin site it started giving me this error
"local variable 'password1' referenced before assignment"
Below i Have include admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label= 'Password' , widget = 
      forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label = 'Password Confirmation', widget = 
     forms.PasswordInput)


    class Meta:
       model = CustomUser
 #with my added feilds in AbstractBaseUser
       fields = ('email','first_name','last_name', 'Mobile', 
       'Aadhar_Card', 'Address','is_supervisor','is_employee','is_driver')

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get(password1)
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get(password2)
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
           raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords Dont Match")
        return password2


   def save(self, commit=True):
       user = super().save(commit=False)
       user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
       if commit:
          user.save()
       return user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clean_password2` method is indeed referencing undefined variables. You need to use strings:

```
password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
```

Comment: I forgot that by password I m refering to variable instead of string. Thanks